# How to convert MySQL date time to date format April 08, 2016?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date say

```
$old_date = $red['added_date']; //2016-04-08 06:24:55
```

I want to convert it into something like: `April 08, 2016`

I am using a code like this:-

```
$review['review_date'] = date($rev['added_date'], 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
```

I am getting this error: `Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given`

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: use this date( ' Fd,  Y',$rev['added_date']);

Comment: Why is the question downvoted? >_<

Comment: Because this is trivial to Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using date function and strtotime. Try :

```
$review['review_date'] = date( 'F m, Y',strtotime($old_date));
```

Comment: It's coming in format 15th March 2016. I want it in format March 15, 2016.

Comment: no jS F Y will give that 15th March 2016 format - 'F m, Y' is correct format

Comment: Oh Sorry! I didn't check the edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this, assuming

```
$review['review_date'] = date('F m, Y', strtotime($rev['added_date']));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your life easy take a look at Carbon, a really simple PHP class that offers a lot of functions for date/time/datetime strings. You can parse to a timestamp, parse from timestamp, create from a date, etc etc, to many to write here.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

With Carbon it would be

```
Carbon::parse($red['added_date']);
```

Answer (score 0):

[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) needs second parameter to be UNIX timestamp (Number of seconds since 1-1-1970).

> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )

First parameter should be date format.

You have interchanged the parameters. Please correct them and it will work.

Corrected code:

```
$review['review_date'] = date('F m, Y',$old_date);
```

Comment: second parameter is supposed to be a unix timestamp not a mysql timestamp.

Comment: You can't use it without strtotime

Comment: Date format corrected, thanks for informing me.